# csv upload to sql using powershell 2.0

Tags: csv, powershell

why I am getting the below error on some machines with PowerShell 2.0.
Working 100% on all machines that have PowerShell 4.0 and some machines with PowerShell 2.0

csv format[image]

1;LNKD;LinkedIn Corp;NAS;Y;N;USD;US;12.31;321;65432;1

[image]

Comment: you should share your import script with us

Comment: @ jisaak script added

Comment: I assume, it is a formatting problem within the value for "Borrow" (or another number-based value). Maybe you should convert the dot-value (i.e. 12.31) to the right Format your SQL uses.

Comment: @Martin that did the trick. thanks

Comment: Do not post error messages or code as screenshots.

Comment: Created it as an answer for future google visits.

Answer (score 0):

I assume, it is a formatting problem within the value for "Borrow" (or another number-based value).
You should convert the dot-value (i.e. 12.31) to the right format your SQL Server uses.